# Instructions to install pepper flash on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: flash, chromium

Can anyone show the way to do this step-wise instead of all in one paragraph?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try to Install it from [here](http://apt://pepperflashplugin-nonfree). If that didn't work  just search in Software Center.

Comment: I checked in the software center and found it but it does not appear "pepperflashplugin non free" but as "Pepper Flash" anyways thank you

Comment: Please Don't ask duplicate questions. Its not allowed here.